# How do I attach an event handler to mustache rendering in CouchApp using evently?

Tags: event-handling, mustache, couchapp

Writing a CouchApp app using evently / mustache. I have a couple of 'widgets', one has a link which triggers an event, and another is set up to listen to it. So far so good. The listening widget has a data.js file which returns an associative array; and mustache.html which uses the values return by data.js to fill in the template.

My data.js is something like

```
function( data ){  
    return {  
      name : 'people'  
    }  
}
```

and the mustache.html is

```
<span id="fadeMe">Hello {{name}}</span>
<a href="#test">Click</a>
```

All that is good. I know how to add an handler to the click event of the link, by creating a click.js file and putting it in selectors/a[href=#test]/click.js

But I also want to animate the #fadeMe span as soon as it's rendered. Is there a 'mustache-has-rendered-it' event? (doesn't look like judging from the files distributed with CouchApp). How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a Javascript function in `after.js`. This will be called after mustache and selectors. You can verify it [in the sources](https://github.com/couchapp/evently/blob/master/lib/jquery.evently.js#L174).

UPDATE: note that Evently is not shipped with python couchapp tool anymore.

Comment: Yes, I found the answer shortly after posting the question but didn't have enough 'reputation' to post it. Thanks for answering it.